# Why aren't two border-box 50% divs side-by-side?

Tags: html, css

I know many techniques for positioning divs side-by-side. However I've never understood why taking two border-box divs with width: 50% doesn't produce side-by-side divs. From what I understand of css, with margin, padding, and border out of the equation this should *absolutely* work.

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
div {
 height: 300px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
}
.left {
 background-color: blue;
}
.right {
 background-color: red;
}
.half {
 width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="half left"></div>
<div class="half right"></div>
```

What am I missing?

**Edit:**
As many people are pointing out, `display: block` will not give me side-by-side behavior. This was a mis-type. I meant to make everything `inline-block`

Comment: Because `div` elements are `display: block` by default (that is, one element per row/line). You need to set them to `float` or `display: inline-block`. Also note that `display: inline-block` will add its own space between the two blocks which would have to be nullified.

Comment: [This w3c article](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) about the Block formatting contexts is relevant: `In a block formatting context, boxes are laid out one after the other, vertically, beginning at the top of a containing block.`

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: Which implies that the next element cannot be on the same line unless the `display` is modified.

Comment: Just  as a note to everyone who is suggesting floats. Yes that solve the issue. But for goodness sake, it's 2015, stop using floats. We have flexbox.

Comment: @Harry You are correct. I would argue it's not a duplicate as that question doesn't ask *why* and the answer is only implied as opposed to given. However, that is a judgement call.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: Absolutely and that's why I didn't go ahead and hammer it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to understand that elements in HTML based on display property are of 2 types -

- Block (eg: div, p, h1 - h6..etc)
- inline (eg: span..etc)

Block level elements appear one below another, or as you may call it being stacked below each other,

whereas,

inline elements are created on the same line **unless** they are specifically styled as `display: block` **OR** if they encounter a `<br />` tag.

## SOLUTION:

1. You can use the property `display:inline-block`

   **Problem:** It will add white spaces and put the second `div` on the next line even with `width: 50%;`. Now, [**there are several**](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) ways to remove whitespaces, you can try any one of them.
2. Use `float: left`on both the `div`'s

```css
    body {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
    }
    div {
     height: 300px;
    }
    .left {
     background-color: blue;
    }
    .right {
     background-color: red;
    }
    .half {
     width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }

    .half-new {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%
    }
```

```html
<h1>Using Float</h1>
<div class="half left"></div>
<div class="half right"></div>
<hr />
<h1>Using inline-block</h1>
<div class="half-new left"></div><!--
--><div class="half-new right"></div>
```

Comment: Please see my edit. I meant to make things inline-block. It was a mistype. Thank you for highlighting the whitespace though I still don't understand where it comes from.

Comment: That link is broken but you imply the solution by explaining that there is a white-space created implicitly by the line-break. Can you edit the answer to say as much and I'll accept?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer you should read this - https://boagworld.com/design/why-whitespace-matters/

Comment: edited the answer and fixed the link. Yes, the white-spaces are added implicitly while using `inline-block`

Comment: @SiddharthThevaril - inline-block don't add space. In OP, the two divs were on different line and new line is rendered as single white-space by html for inline elements and therefore there was less room than 50% available for second div(100% - 50% - width of a white-space character)

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons:

- Div elements are `display: block` by default
- You have space between the elements and space takes up … um space.

Change the display property and remove the space.

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
div {
 height: 300px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
.left {
 background-color: blue;
}
.right {
 background-color: red;
}
.half {
 width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="half left"></div><div class="half right"></div>
```

Comment: Or he could float them left for example too,

Comment: *space takes up … um space* > Can you verify this by scientific facts?

Comment: @NicoO —You could edit the snippet and put the white space back between the two elements.

Comment: @j08691 — Floating is very good for [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/images/float2p.png) but once you start using it to just put two things side by side you venture closer to having to start clearing things as well.

Comment: I think my attempt to make a joke failed miserably ;) I did not meant to waste your time. Sorry.

Comment: In [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/1529630) there is a full list of ways to deal with the space problem.

Comment: Thanks for that link @Oriol that and the andswer of Sidesec provided the clue - there's a whitespace coming from the line break